# Prove a module $R_1$ is not isomorphic to $R_1\oplus R_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The context is the uniqueness of finitely generated PID module decomposition. The text I am using is Aluffi's Algebra Chapter 0.

For the uniqueness, it reduces to prove (where $R$ is PID, $q$ are prime elements in $R$, and $r_i,s_i$ are increasing)
\begin{align*}
\frac{R}{q^{r_1}}\oplus\cdots \oplus \frac{R}{q^{r_n}}\cong \frac{R}{q^{s_1}}\oplus\cdots \oplus \frac{R}{q^{s_m}}
\end{align*}
implies $n=m$ and $r_i=s_i$ for all $i$. The hint given is consider the homomophism $m\rightarrow qm$. By induction, if $m=n$ we can show $r_i$ and $s_i$ are the same. But how can I show $m=n$?

It seems we have to eliminate the possibility that
\begin{align*}
\frac{R}{q^{r}}\cong \frac{R}{q^{r}}\oplus \frac{R}{q^{s}}
\end{align*}
where $s\leq r$. This is simple if $R$ is finite (i.e. finite abelian group case). However, when $R$ is infinite, I stuck at this question. I tried to show $R/q^{r}$ fail to satisfy the universal property of the product, but it seems does not work.

Does anyone have any comments or ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you mod out by the *image* of the map $m\mapsto qm$, you will get a direct sum of copies of $R/q$. You get $n$ copies in the first decomposition, and $m$ copies in the second. Now tensor to the field of fractions to use well-definedness of dimension for vector spaces yo conclude $n=m$.